# Fill vector of string vectors from input file

Tags: c++, string, vector

I would really appreciate the help here. I need to fill a vector of string vectors using text from an input file. I really have no idea how to start off.

I have something like this in a function to read in the words, but I keep getting a compiler error saying I can't push back a string, so I know I'm on the wrong track. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
ifstream input(filename);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    string line;
    getline(input, line);
    stringstream temp(line);
    string tempWord;
    temp >> tempWord;
    words[i][j].push_back(tempWord);
  }
```

Comment: Might be `words[i][j] = tempWord;` ?

Comment: How did you declare `words`?

Comment: It's declared vector<vector<string> > words; and is passed by reference to the function I'm using to try and read in some words.

Comment: Also, the problem guarantees that only four lines of text will be in the file, so that's where that random 4 is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If words is a `vector<vector<string>>` then `words[i][j]` is accessing a `string`. What you might looking to do is is `words[i][j] = tempWord;`.  `string` also has a function `.push_back()` but takes a `char` which is why the error you are getting is that you can't push_back a string, the `push_back()` for `string`s is for appending characters to the string. Also depending on how you declared `words`, if you didn't give sizes, `words[i][j]` might be accessing out of range and a better approach would be to do `words[i].push_back(tempWord)`.  Also looking at your for loops I'm not sure of your intent for which words from the file you want but currently as your code is, it will read in the first 16 lines of the file and place the first "word" from each into your `words` object.  If your intent is instead to have a vector of vectors of string where each subvector is the words in a line then something like below might be better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string filename = "testfile.txt";
    std::ifstream input(filename.c_str());
    if(!input){
        std::cerr << "Error in opening file: " << filename << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > words;
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(input, line)){
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << line;
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        while (!ss.eof()) {
            std::string tempStr;
            ss >> tempStr;
            row.push_back(tempStr);
        }
        words.push_back(row);
    }
    //... then do something with words here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really had no idea how to start. My program kept crashing and I guess it is because my for loop was messed up. You were right, I was trying to have the subvector as a line/sentence of words. Also, how might I access various words? A for loop?

Comment: `words[0][0]` would access the first word on the first line, `words[0][1]` would access second word on first line, etc. But you should also check the size so you're not accessing out of range, words.size() would give you the number of lines, words[0].size() would give you number of number of words in first line, etc or you can use .at(), which would access elements with range checking, so the first word on first line `words.at(0).at(0)`. If you did `words.at(5).at(0)` and there weren't 6 lines in the file you would get a std::out_of_range exception but `words[5][0]` only might seg fault